# Delete records from html table, but keep in database table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Include config file
    require_once 'config.php';

    // Prepare a delete statement
    $sql = "UPDATE data SET is_deleted=1 WHERE id = ?";
   // $sql="DELETE from data WHERE id = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_POST["id"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter
    if(empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

I want to remove records from html table. Instead of using delete query I used an update query in order to keep the deleted record in database. But the problem is that I need to remove deleted records from html table.

Comment: Where is your code for the HTML Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided the query where you are selecting what to display nor the html we have to guess what you are doing

I might take this approach

```
$sql = "Select * from data where is_deleted!=1";
```

or grab them all and only show if the is_deleted is false

**PHP**

```
$sql = "Select * from data";
echo "<table>";
foreach ($result as $row){?>
    <tr class='<?php echo $row['is_deleted']==1?"hide":"show";?>'>
      <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Of course there are so many assumptions made here

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to do soft delete like you need to add a field called isdeleted or delete whatever you want which stores Boolean value then change the status from 1 to 0 if user delete any entry from the HTML table,fetch only those records whose value of isdeleted or deleted is 1.

Answer (score 0):

As you say delete from html but still have data in database so you need just remove at a time `td` by using jquery and also update your data's row just like `status` is `0/1`. 0 for deleted and 1 for active. you can use ajax for update your record.
For example you have a table like that

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblParticipantList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Adress</th>
            <th>Redeem Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="columnId" id="customerPartial_94">
            <td data-field="NAME">Attn Donna</td>
            <td data-field="ADDRESS">3046 Lavon Drive Newyork America 7504</td>
            <td data-field="SECURITY_REDEMPTION_CD"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="columnId" id="customerPartial_95">
            <td data-field="NAME">F 1 La 1</td>
            <td data-field="ADDRESS">Asd 1 s 1 Ci 1 s</td>
            <td data-field="SECURITY_REDEMPTION_CD"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Remove TD at specified Row and Column

```
$('#tblParticipantList > tr').eq(rowNum).children('td').eq(colNum).remove();
```